# How does Haskell infer the type of (+).(+)

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Why the type of `(+).(+)` is `(Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` ?

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

I tried but didn't know how to turn out `(Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

```
(+) :: Num i => i -> i -> i
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
(+) :: Num j => j -> j -> j

(+) . (+) :: (i -> (i -> i)) -> ((j -> j) -> i) -> ((j -> j) -> (i -> i))
where: 
  b = i
  c = i -> i
  a = j -> j
```

Could someone help and give me analysis steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My explanations tend to have more words and fewer formulae - apologies if this isn't helpful, but I'm left a little unsatisfied by the other answers so I thought I'd explain it in a slightly different way.

Clearly you already have a good idea of what the various parts do. Let's focus on the function composition operator `.`. It takes two functions, and returns the new function which first applies the function on the right of `.` to the argument, then applies the function on the  left of `.` to the result of that.

So in `(+).(+)` we'll start with the function on the right of `.`: `(+)`. This has type `(Num a) => a -> a -> a` - that is, it takes two arguments which must be the same type, and that type must be an instance of `Num`. And then it returns a value of the same type.

Recall that, because of currying, this is equivalent to `(Num a) => a -> (a -> a)`. That is, it takes an instance of `Num`, and returns a function from that same type to that same type.

Now we must compose it with another function - one that takes its result type as input. What is that other function? It's `(+)` again! But we know that, in order for the composition to type-check, we must feed it that function type: `a -> a` (where `a` is an instance of `Num`). As we already saw, this isn't a problem, as `(+)` can take *any type that is an instance of `Num`*. That can include `a -> a`, when we have the appropriate instance. And this explains why the final type has the 2 constraints `Num a` and `Num (a -> a)`.

Now it's easy to put everything together. Leaving off the constraints (which we've already dealt with), we schematically have:

```
(+)                                 .     (+)
(a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))        a -> (a -> a)
```

So in the type signature of `(.)`, which I'll write as `(c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> (b -> d)`, we have `a` as `b`, `a -> a` as `c`, and `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` as `d`. Substituting these in, we get the final type (`b  -> d`) as:

```
a -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))
```

Which we can rewrite as

```
a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

by removing unnecessary parentheses, after recalling that function arrows are right-associative.

Answer (score 6):

A different approach:

```
((+).(+)) x y z
= (+) ((+) x) y z
= ((x +) + y) z
```

Now notice:

```
(x +) + y
```

is the sum of two *functions*, since one of the arguments is a function.  Let's assume `x :: a` since we have to start somewhere (this assumption does not necessarily mean `a` is going to appear in the final type, we just want to give it a name to start our reasoning process)

```
x :: a
```

Then

```
(x +) :: a -> a
y :: a -> a      -- since the operands of + have to be the same type
```

Also we are adding `x` in `(x +)` which gives us `Num a`, and we are adding the functions which give us `Num (a -> a)`  (at this point, this is essentially an error, since no sane person defines an instance of `Num` for functions –– it's possible, but it's a bad idea).

Anyway, the expression we have just analyzed is the sum of two things of type `a -> a`, so the result must be of type `a -> a` as well.

```
((x +) + y) z    -- since the result of + has to have the same type 
^^^^^^^^^^^      --                                    as its operands 
  a -> a
```

Therefore, `z :: a`.

So finally the whole expression is typed

```
(+).(+) :: a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
           ^    ^^^^^^^^    ^    ^
           x       y        z    final result
```

plus the constraints that we picked up along the way.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there.

```
(Num i =>)
b = i
c = i -> i
(Num j =>)
a = j -- this is different, you associated b,c correctly but a wrongly
b = j -> j
=> i = j -> j -- ( by i = b = j -> j )
=> c = (j -> j) -> (j -> j) -- ( by c = i -> i, i = j -> j )
=> (+) . (+) :: a -> c = j -> ((j -> j) -> (j -> j)) 
    = j -> (j -> j) -> j -> j -- ( simplifying brackets )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

If you apply two functions to it you get in pseudocode:
(+) . (+) -> a -> c

So what is the type of a? It has the same type as the first argument 
of the second function you pass into (.). You can rewrite the type 
of (+) with brackets and get
(+) :: a -> (a -> a)

From that we know that

a :: a
b :: (a -> a)

Now that we know what a and b are, let's look at the first argument of (.).

It's (+) applied by an argument b :: (a -> a). So we get
(a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))

so we found the type of c:
c :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) 
and since we can remove the second pair of brackets
c :: (a -> a) -> a -> a

if we plug our findings into 

(+) . (+) -> a -> c

we get 

(+) . (+) :: a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Answer (score 1):

Type derivation is a purely mechanical procedure:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(.) :: (       b -> c     ) ->  (       a -> b     )  -> a -> c

(.)    ((+) :: t -> (t->t))     ((+) :: s -> (s->s))  :: a -> c
----------------------------------------------------
            b ~ t, c ~ t->t,          a ~ s, b ~ s->s    s -> (t -> t)
            Num t                     Num s              s -> (b -> b)
            Num b                     Num s              s -> ((s->s) -> (s->s))
            Num (s->s)                Num s              s -> ((s->s) -> (s->s))
```

`(+) . (+)` is the same as `(.) (+) (+)`.

Answer (score 0):

The types of `(.)` and `(+)` are like this:

```hs
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

We can relabel to avoid confusion:

```
(+) :: Num i => i -> i -> i -- the first (+)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(+) :: Num j => j -> j -> j -- the second (+)
```

Now, lets work out the type of `(+) (.)`. This is `(.)` with one argument applied, so the result will be `(a -> b) -> a -> c`, and we have matched `(b -> c)` with the type of our first `(+)` so:

```
(b -> c) = Num i => i -> i -> i
b = i
c = i -> i

(+) (.) :: (a -> b) -> a -> c
= Num i => (a -> i) -> a -> c -- replacing b
= Num i => (a -> i) -> a -> (i -> i) -- replacing c
= Num i => (a -> i) -> a -> i -> i -- simplifying
```

Now, we can apply the second argument to this. The result will be `a -> i -> i`, and we have matched `(a -> i)` with the type of our second `(+)` so:

```
(a -> i) = Num j => j -> j -> j
a = j
i = j -> j

(+) (.) (+) :: Num i => a -> i -> i
= (Num i, Num j) => j -> i -> i -- replacing a
= (Num (j -> j), Num j) => j -> (j -> j) -> (j -> j) -- replacing i
= (Num (j -> j), Num j) => j -> (j -> j) -> j -> j -- simplifying
```