# Signature of `join bimap` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference, parametric-polymorphism

In one of the solutions on codewars I've met the following expression:

```
join bimap
```

where `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`,
and   `bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d`. The resulting expression has the type: `Bifunctor p => (c -> d) -> p c c -> p d d`.

I can guess that the type of `bimap` could be written in the form
`(->) (a->b) ((->) (c->d) p a c -> p b d)`, but  I can't figure out how `p a c` turns to `p c c` and `p b d` to `p d d`.
Please, give me some hints how to untangle this puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let’s look at the type of `join` as applied to a function. Let’s say you have a function `f :: t -> u -> v`; or, equivalently, `f :: (->) t ((->) u v)`. We can attempt to unify this with `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` by comparing the two types:

```
           (->) t ((->) u v)
Monad m => m      (m      a) -> m a
```

Thus, we can attempt to unify the types by setting `m ~ (->) t` and `a ~ v`:

```
(->) t ((->) u v)
(->) t ((->) t v) -> (->) t v
```

But there is a problem: we additionally need `t ~ u` in order for these types to match up! Thus we can conclude that `join` can only applied to a function when the first two arguments have the same type — and if they are not, we can only apply `join` to that function if there is a way to make them equal.

Now, think about `bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d`. Normally, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `p` may be any type. But if you want to apply `join` to `bimap`, this adds the constraint that the first two arguments of `bimap` must have the same type: that is, `(a -> b) ~ (c -> d)`. From this we can conclude that `a ~ c` and `b ~ d`. But, of course, this implies that `p a c` must be the same as `p a a`, and `p b d` the same as `p b b`, solving the puzzle.

Comment: That makes sense. Shouldn't it be (->) t v in the last line?

Comment: @KarenFisher Not sure where you’re talking about, where exactly do you think it should be `(->) t v`?

Comment: (->) t ((->) t v) -> (->) t v instead of (->) t ((->) t v) -> (->) t a

Comment: Whoops, yes, you’re quite right. Fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full instantiation of `join` and `bimap` using visible type applications. It's messy as there is a lot happening behind the scenes

```
joinBimap :: forall bi a a'. Bifunctor bi => (a -> a') -> (bi a a -> bi a' a')
joinBimap = join @((->) (a -> a')) @(bi a a -> bi a' a') (bimap @bi @a @a' @a @a')
```

Here is the output of `join @((->) _) bimap` in ghci, with and without `bimap`

```
>> :set -XTypeApplications
>> import Control.Monad (join)
>> import Data.Bifunctor (Bifunctor(bimap))
>>
>> :t join @((->) _) bimap
.. :: Bifunctor p => (c -> b) -> p c c -> p b b
>> :t join @((->) _)
.. :: (_ -> _ -> a) -> _ -> a
```

The only sensible implementation with the type of `join @((->) _)` is

```
joinReader :: (env -> env -> a) -> (env -> a)
joinReader (·) env = env · env
```

---

It is tricky to introduce type variable in ghci. We don't have the means to write something like `\@a @a' -> join @((->) (a -> a'))`.

One way without adding arguments to the function is to give it a partial type signature that quantifies the new type variables

```
>> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
>> :set -XPartialTypeSignatures -Wno-partial-type-signatures
>>
>> :t join @((->) (a -> a')) bimap :: forall a a'. _
.. :: Bifunctor p => (a -> a') -> p a a -> p a' a'
```

It is also possible to take a proxy object which it has to be applied to to get the expected term. If the type variables are more than one, or of other kinds than `Type` a proxy object like `\(_ :: _ a a') -> ..` can be used.

```
>> :t (\(_ :: a) (_ :: a') -> join @((->) (a -> a'))) undefined undefined
.. :: ((a1 -> a') -> (a1 -> a') -> a2) -> (a1 -> a') -> a2
>>
>> import Data.Function ((&))
>> :t undefined & \(_ :: _ a a') -> join @((->) (a -> a')
.. :: ((a1 -> a') -> (a1 -> a') -> a2) -> (a1 -> a') -> a2
```

Answer (score 0):

Type derivation is a purely mechanical affair:

```
join foo x = foo x x
=>
join bimap x = bimap x x 
  :: ( ((a->b)~(c->d)) => p a c -> p b d ) 
  ~  (   (a~c, b~d)    => p a c -> p b d ) 
  ~  p c c -> p d d
```

And again, slower:

```
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
bimap (x :: a -> b) (y :: c -> d) :: Bifunctor p => p a c -> p b d
                     x :: a -> b
----------------------------------
                         a~c, b~d
----------------------------------
bimap (x :: a -> b) (x :: a -> b) :: Bifunctor p => p c c -> p d d
```

And why is `join foo x = foo x x`, you ask? We don't even know what this `foo` is? But we see that the result of `join foo` is a function, as we apply it to an `x`. And with functions,

```
join :: Monad m        => m      (m      a)  -> m      a
     :: Monad ((->) r) => (->) r ((->) r a)  -> (->) r a
     :: Monad ((->) r) => (r  -> (r  ->  a)) -> (r ->  a)
     :: Monad ((->) r) => (r  ->  r  ->  a ) ->  r ->  a 
     foo               :: (r  ->  r  ->  a ) 
---------------------------------------------
join foo                                     ::  r ->  a
```

`join foo` is a function; hence `foo` is a function, `foo :: r -> r -> a`:

```
join foo                                         x =   a
  where
  a = foo                  x      x -- :: a
```

Here we've even derived an *implementation* for `join` on functions, mechanically, from its type.

Comment: related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891%20mechanical), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55532857/849891), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691152/849891).